# CSV File , Text to Column using Panda

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
def Text2Col(df_File):
    for i in range(0,len(df_File)):  
        with open(df_File.iloc[i]['Input']) as inf:
            with open(df_File.iloc[i]['Output'], 'w') as outf:
                i=0
                for line in inf:
                    i=i+1
                    if i==2 or i==3:
                        continue
                    outf.write(','.join(line.split(';')))
```

Above code is used to convert a csv file from text to column.
This code makes all values string ( because split() ) which is problematic for me.
I tried using map function but cant make it.

Is there any other way in which I can do this.

My input file has 5 columns, the first column is string, the second is int and the rest are float.

I think it required some modification in last statement

```
  outf.write(','.join(line.split(';')))
```

Please let me know if any other input is required.

Comment: Please share expected output.

Comment: Expected output is a CSV file separated in column from input csv file which " ; " separated

Comment: why are you not reading it through pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, trying to help here. If this doesn't work, please specify in your question, what you're missing or what else needs to be done:

Use pandas to [read in a csv file](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
```

If you have a header on the first row, then use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', header=0)
```

If you have a tab delimiter instead of a comma delimiter, then use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', header=0, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you !

Following Code worked:

```
def Text2Col(df_File):
    for i in range(0,len(df_File)):  
        df = pd.read_csv(df_File.iloc[i]['Input'],sep=';')
        df = df[df.index != 0]
        df= df[df.index != 1]
        df.to_csv(df_File.iloc[i]['Output']) 



File_List="File_List.csv"
df_File=pd.read_csv(File_List)
Text2Col(df_File)
```

Input files are kept in same folder with same name as mentioned in File_List.xls
Output files will be created in same folder with separated in column. I deleted row 0 and 1 for my use. One can skip or add depending upon his requirement.
In above code df_file is dataframe contain two column list, first column is input file name and second column is output file name.